# how can I get only lookup icon functionality from inputField in visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to include lookup Icon on my VF page. I tried doing custom lookup page but it is very time consuming and tedious job. So, I decided to use Contact;s AccountID field using inputField. I get total field with inputbox and lookup icon. I dont want input box. I just want lookup Icon to get Account ID and I want to select picklist value accordingly. Please help me to figure out this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the input field from the page by using CSS that is qualified by the element name (i.e. hide the `input.hideField` but not the `a.hideField` as the `styleClass` is applied to both the field and the lookup icon):

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">

<style>
input.hideField {
    display: none;
}
</style>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.AccountId}" styleClass="hideField"/>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

The input field remains in the DOM and is populated by the selection from the popup.